# Получить значение из Промиса (да дубликат, сорри)

Tags: javascript, promise, return

Нужно вытянуть из Промиса значение в переменную
Используя только синтаксис Promise

```
let pr = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    let random = 1
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if (random>0) { resolve('plus') }
        else { reject('minus') }
    }, 1000)
})
```

Если записываю в новую переменную так, то туда ожидаемо попадает Промис

```
let result = pr.then(res=>res).catch(err=>err)
console.log(result) //Promise {<fulfilled>: 'plus'}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, тогда единственный вариант - это присвоение значения внутри then, catch, как показано ниже ?
Или есть еще вариант как присвоид значение, а не сам Промис, переменной используя синтаксис then, catch?

```
let result;
let error;
pr.then(res=>result=res).catch(err=>error=err)
//1 second later
console.log(result) //plus - можно как-то использовать дальше
```

Используя async, await (хз как это переписать на setTImeout, поэтому пример с урлом), присвоить данные из Промиса можно только используя промежуточную асинхронную функцию и ее вызов ?

```
async function check() {
    let res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    return await res.json()
}
let result
async function give() { result = await check() }
give();
console.log(result) //{userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}
```

Или аналог в виде самовызывающейся асинхронки ?

```
(async ()=> result=await check())()
console.log(result) //{userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}
console.log(result.id) //1 - можно как-то использовать дальше
```

Так же вопрос, если попытатся вывести результат сразу, то ничего не выйдет, так как он еще не получен.
Как тогда быть в таком случает ?

```
let pr = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
 let random = 1 setTimeout(()=>{
  if (random>0) { resolve('plus') }
  else { reject('minus') } }, 1000) })
let result = pr.then(res=>res).catch(err=>err)
console.log(result) //undefined - Промис еще не вернул результат
```

Как результат использовать дальше ?

Comment: «Но как тогда его использовать дальше ?» — дождаться его появления через then или await, вы в своём вопросе уже описали все способы как это делать

Comment: *"Но как тогда его использовать дальше ?"* --- смотри этот ответ:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1476674/191482   по факту, вся работа с запросами в таком случае (если надо сложить результат в переменную и потом где-то использовать) сведётся к оформлению либо класса, либо модуля,  либо обёртки над всем происходящим в виде асинхронной анонимной самовызывающейся функции.....и вот этот вот console.log придётся помещать именно внутрь этого всего, а не вне

Comment: @andreymal я в своем же вопросе, показал пример, который в такой способ - выводит undefined.
let pr = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{ let random = 1; setTimeout(()=>{ if (random>0) { resolve('plus') } else { reject('minus') } }, 1000) }); let result; let error; pr.then(res=>result=res).catch(err=>error=err); console.log(result)

Comment: @Mr.StupidQuestions ваш последний пример вообще синтаксически некорректен. Но даже если починить синтаксис, console.log выводит `Promise { <state>: "pending" }` как и должно быть, никаких undefined там нет

Comment: @andreymal тут в комментах неудобно код вставлять. Расставил что б все в линию работало, и console.log выводит undefined
let pr = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{ let random = 1; setTimeout(()=>{ if (random>0) { resolve('plus') } else { reject('minus') } }, 1000) }); let result; let error; pr.then(res=>result=res).catch(err=>error=err); console.log(result)

Comment: @Mr.StupidQuestions undefined — это значение, которое возвращает сама функция console.log, сделайте `console.log(2+2)` и вы тоже увидите undefined, промисы здесь вообще ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal я вот про это

let pr = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    let random = 1;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if (random>0){
            resolve('plus')}
        else {
            reject('minus')}
    }, 1000) });
let result;
let error;
pr.then(res=>result=res).catch(err=>error=err);
console.log('2+2', result)

[2+2](https://prnt.sc/FFvKmuqpaMHE)
[undefined](https://prnt.sc/rkN9Cq76VOtS) В обоих случаях возвращает undefined

Comment: @Mr.StupidQuestions а в этом коде вы выполняете console.log раньше чем отработает then, поэтому в result значения ещё нет. А чтобы оно там было, нужно дождаться его появления, а чтобы его дождаться, нужно использовать then или await

Comment: @andreymal да причина верна, но в этом же коде, выше я уже использовал then, catch, для записи результата в переменные (result или error) - pr.then(res=>result=res).catch(err=>error=err)

Comment: @Mr.StupidQuestions «я уже использовал then» — нет, для console.log вы НЕ использовали then

Comment: @andreymal вы предлагаете console.log(result) поместить внуть then, где переменной result присваивалось значение из Промиса ? pr.then(res=>{result=res; console.log(result)}); Так ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тут проблема в том, что синхронный код после такой асинхронной самовызывающейся функции выполнится раньше этой фукнции.
Например: let result=0;
let pr=new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    let random=1;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if (random>0) { resolve('plus') }
        else { reject('minus') }
    }, 1000)
});
(async ()=>{
    result=await pr;
    console.log('result inside ', result)
})();
console.log('result out', result)
Сначала отработает синхронный код после самовызывающейся функции, где результат еще не получен - result out undefined, затем сама фукнция

Comment: @Mr.StupidQuestions я дал конкретную ссылку с конкретным ответом.... зачем ты упорно пытаешься писать `console.log('result out', result)`  вне  async  функции  остаётся загадкой...